# htaccess and htpasswd protect a root subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, passwords, .htpasswd

I know this is a common question, but I just can't figure out how to do it.

After many unsuccessful attempts, dozens of tutorials and SO posts I gave up and decided to ask a new question here.

So, this is what I have:

- a vary basic file host without the ability to alter any Apache settings
- a subdomain provider
- following file and directory structure:

```
-root
|-subfolder1
|-subfolder2
 |-subfolder1
  |-index.html
  |-somescript.php
```

Now I just want to protect the folder "subfolder2" and all of its contents.

I managed to protect a subfolder of a subfolder of the root directory, but not a subfolder within the root directory itself.

I am totally lost.

Please, can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question you want to forbid the access to any URL which has `subfolder2` in it, if this is the case then please try placing these rules into your .htaccess file. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} subfolder2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

WOW!

Your code was not needed.
All I had to do was clearing the cache and cookies and then the login prompt popped up. That simple.
Thanks for your effort though!

BTW. this is what I have done so far:

file and directory structure as follows:

```
-root
...
|-subfolder2
 |-subfolder1
 |-.htaccess
 |-.htpasswd
 |-index.html
 |-script.php
```

.htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /users/XYZ/root/subfolder2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

.htpasswd file:

```
MrX:$blah1blah2blah3.some.encoded.password
```

Cleared browser cache and cookies.
Now when I go to http://XYZ.domain.com/subfolder2 the "login" prompt pops up and that's all I needed.
There's no secret or vulnerable data in this folder, I just don't want bots and crawlers to browse it.

Many thanks anyway
stay safe and have a nice pre new years eve time